# sympy: how to simplify across multiple expressions

Tags: python, sympy

I have a set of `sympy` expressions like this (a few hundred of them):

```
>>> foo = parse_expr('X | Y')
>>> bar = parse_expr('(Z & X) | (Z & Y)')
>>> baz = parse_expt('AAA & BBB') # not needed for this example; just filler
```

I can simplify one in isolation:

```
>>> simplify(bar)
Z & (X | Y)
```

Is there a way to simplify, including the whole set of variables available?

```
>>> mysimplify(bar, include=(foo,bar,baz))
Z & foo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of [Common Subexpresion Elimination](https://docs.sympy.org/1.0/modules/simplify/simplify.html#module-sympy.simplify.cse_main). You must use it in combination with `simplify` by combining all your expressions into a single artificial expression (for example, by passing them as arguments to a fictitious function). I don't think that it will always work as desired, however on a loose analogue of your example it produces the expected result:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: myexprlist = sympify('listofexpr(x|y, (z&x)|(z&y))')

In [3]: cse(simplify(myexprlist))
Out[3]: ([(x0, Or(x, y))], [listofexpr(x0, And(x0, z))])
```

The first entry in the result is a list of introduced subexpressions. In this case
the subexpression `x|y` has been denoted with `x0`. The second part of the result is the simplified expression (packaged into a list, since the input can be a list of expressions).